# Is there a function to call the estimated waiting time for a Job on the IBM Quantum Platform?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I was trying to write a script that obtains current Information about a Job on the IBM Quantum Platform using Qiskit.

I managed to call the current status with the JobID, but it seems, like there is no function or API call that makes it possible to display the current estimated waiting time for the Job.

In addition, although I managed to gather the information about the current status of the Job (e.g. queued) the output I get is NONE, maybe we can manage to fix this aswell.

Can anybody help me out?

I tried including a function to call the estimated waiting time, but it seems, that there is no API call.

Answer (score 4):

The [IBM Qiskit documentation](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/monitor-job) states that you are able to monitor the job status, as well as previous jobs, and even [estimate the runtime](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/estimate-job-run-time). But there's no current ability to request an estimate of queue time from IBM.